# My Symfony RegistrationFormType does not submit

Tags: php, symfony, twig, registration, symfony-forms

I generated the user registration code with the symfony console make:registration command. But when I fill out the Registration form, and submit, var_dump($ form->isSubmitted()) always shows false, so I fail to actually create the users. What can explain this? How to correct?

This is the generated controller file:

```
#[Route('/register', name: 'app_register')]
public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder): Response
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
   
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // encode the plain password
        dd(1);
        $user->setPassword(
            $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                $user,
                $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
            )
        );

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        // generate a signed url and email it to the user
        $this->emailVerifier->sendEmailConfirmation('app_verify_email', $user,
            (new TemplatedEmail())
                ->from(new Address('isbbethesda@gmail.com', 'Bethesda Administration'))
                ->to($user->getEmail())
                ->subject('Please Confirm your Email')
                ->htmlTemplate('registration/confirmation_email.html.twig')
        );
        // do anything else you need here, like send an email

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home');
    }

    return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
        'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

This is the generated form type:

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email')
        ->add('agreeTerms', CheckboxType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,
            'constraints' => [
                new IsTrue([
                    'message' => 'You should agree to our terms.',
                ]),
            ],
        ])
        ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
            // instead of being set onto the object directly,
            // this is read and encoded in the controller
            'mapped' => false,
            'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password'],
            'constraints' => [
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                ]),
                new Length([
                    'min' => 6,
                    'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                    // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                    'max' => 4096,
                ]),
            ],
        ])
    ;
}
```

}

This is the generated twig file:

```
{{ form_start(registrationForm) }}
    {{ form_row(registrationForm.email) }}
    {{ form_row(registrationForm.plainPassword, {
        label: 'Password'
    }) }}
    {{ form_row(registrationForm.agreeTerms) }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Register</button>
{{ form_end(registrationForm) }}
```

This file were generated by the `symfony console make:registration` command. Please where is the problem?

Comment: I guess you'll need to register a `SubmitType::class` as well to the form - [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/submit.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add a [SubmitType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/submit.html) in your form:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

//...
$builder
            ->add('email')
            ->add('agreeTerms', CheckboxType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => [
                    new IsTrue([
                        'message' => 'You should agree to our terms.',
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('plainPassword', PasswordType::class, [
                // instead of being set onto the object directly,
                // this is read and encoded in the controller
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => ['autocomplete' => 'new-password'],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'Please enter a password',
                    ]),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 6,
                        'minMessage' => 'Your password should be at least {{ limit }} characters',
                        // max length allowed by Symfony for security reasons
                        'max' => 4096,
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn'],
            ])
        ;
```

And update your twig file:

```
{{ form_start(registrationForm) }}
    {{ form_row(registrationForm.email) }}
    {{ form_row(registrationForm.plainPassword, {
        label: 'Password'
    }) }}
    {{ form_row(registrationForm.agreeTerms) }}

    {{ form_row(registrationForm.submit) }}
{{ form_end(registrationForm) }}
```

Comment: I did it, it does not works. It sems as a general proble in my code. Because, im seeing the same issue in another formtype

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `data_class` in the form type.

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    // ...

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it, it does not works. It sems as a general proble in my code. Because, im seeing the same issue in another formtype

Answer (score 0):

I was able to detect the submission of my form by adding the following lines

```
  $form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()));
```

before submitting as specified on the page https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/direct_submit.html
Thank you for your guidance. May this help anyone who will face this problem.